# Hello World with Spring-Boot using Groovy and IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a basic Groovy script [1] based on Spring Boot running from IntelliJ. However I run into the problem that servlet 2 API is used instead of 3. See stack trace [2] below.

If I run the same script from the command line using Spring Boot CLI it runs fine.
So what do I need to change?

any help is much appreciated,

Stephan

PS the groovy script might be simplified because it is just a copy/paste from java

[1]

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework.boot', module='spring-boot-starter-web', version='1.1.7.RELEASE')

import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloWorld  {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
    }
}
```

[2]

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:166)
```

Comment: i get this same error on commandline with groovy 2.3.6

Comment: cmd line works fine for me using Groovy 2.3.6
($ spring run HelloWorld.groovy)

Comment: Then you should add how you run it on CLI and how you run it in IDEA.  From your question i assumed: `groovy HelloWorld` on CLI and `Shift+F10` on the class or on `main`.  The later would be the equivalent of running it with groovy on CLI (well more or less).

Answer (score 0):

Check the Groovy distribution being used by your IDE. I think the default distro still has servlet jars in it and they will be on the classpath by default (there may be a way to disable that, but it will depend on the tooling). You need to remove them, or copy the Groovy distro and remove the bad jars and then point the IDE at that instead.

Comment: I was thinking in the same lines, so I removed servlet-api-2.4.jar, but with the same result. Also, the cmd line uses the same Groovy distribution and that does work...

I thought that it had to do with instructing Spring-boot to use the 3.0 api. There is some documentation that you can give Spring the opportunity to do so. (iirc SpringApplicationBuilder). However I would expect SpringApplication already to do so... Clueless

Answer (score 0):

I 'fixed' this by adding javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar to the class path before the groovy jars. I.e. moving it **above** the groovy 2.3.6 library in the Dependency tab of the Module settings.

For now I downloaded the servlet jar manually, maybe I can improve this with a grape.